# GPS over CAN bus

Tags: gps, protocol, can

**How is GPS data typically sent over CAN bus?**

Some context:

I'm looking to simulate sending and for receiving GPS data (using a Linux-running embedded device with CAN interface), to work side-by-side with "real" devices on CAN bus. I've had trouble finding good material with Google, thanks to the name of the CAN bus and many standards being closed, and many apparently related product pages not having downloadable technical documentation.

I'm after the real, relevant protocols that are used in real devices and vehicles, and documented in a standard or in devices' official technical documentation. Or just key words and phrases for further research would be cool too, if question is otherwise too broad.

Comment: Seems off topic to me = "SocketCAN is a set of open source CAN drivers". Maybe you have more success on StackOverflow instead.

Comment: @MikedeKlerk Yeah, could be. I went by *"a communication scheme"* being on topic according to the help pages, but I'm not sure if that includes protocols used over CAN bus...

Comment: [NMEA 2000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_2000) uses CAN as transmission medium.  The spec isn't free of charge.  Don't know how widely NMEA 2000 is adopted.

Comment: AFAIK, There isn't any standard way for sending, specifically GPS data. Is your GPS device CAN Compatible??

Comment: @Swanand Don't have a CAN GPS device yet. So it looks like I'll just pack NMEA stream in CAN packets with something like ISO-TP (which has a rough/partial spec at Wikipedia), and then deal with any actual device according to its specs.

Comment: Just for fun, a link to PDF found by Google, describing the protocol used by one device: http://www.caemax.de/Downloads/QIC/QIC_GPS_DE.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing answer based on comments in order to close the question:

There is no common protocol really, but [NMEA 2000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_2000) covers this, quote from Wikipedia:

> Electrically [NMEA 2000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_2000) is compatible with the Controller Area Network
>   ("CAN Bus") used on road vehicles and fuel engines. The higher-level
>   protocol format is based on [SAE J1939](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J1939)

Unfortunately the NMEA2000 spec is not publicly available. Also, GPS receivers with a CAN interface might use their own custom protocol, too ([example](http://www.caemax.de/Downloads/QIC/QIC_GPS_DE.pdf)).